# How to center align a Card with left aligned text?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-design, material-ui

Newbie question here.

I'm trying to have a card with a width that doesn't span the entire window. I have a cardStyle I've defined below.

```
cardStyle:{
    width: '95vw'
    align? : 'center?'
    textAlign? : 'default or left or something'
}
```

I want my card to be centered but the text to have the usual left alignment. I can't seem to figure this out. If I drop it in a div, I get everything centered.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You need to show the HTML so we can know what the proper CSS on it should be. But the `text-align` should default to `left` unless it's inheriting a different value from a higher element. There is no `align` property. Also, CSS rules don't place a colon after the selector, only between properties and values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, but the simplest is to have your "card" be a block level element (an element that renders on its own line). It's width needs to be less than 100% and its left and right margins should be set to `auto`. The `auto` applied to both the left and right margins tells the browser to split whatever space is left over equally between the two, thus the element gets "pushed" to the center of the viewport.

The alignment of the contents of the block element is separate from the position of the element itself. `left` is the default `text-align` value and it is an inherited value.

```css
.card {
    width: 50vw;
    margin:auto;
    border:1px solid black;
    background:#e0e0e0;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">I am the card</div>
```